# No Internet in android emulator

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I have my office machine and we are required to connect to VPN's etc when we are working at office. That is okay but now a strange this is happening to me that if I am not connected to the VPN I get no internet on my android emulator on windows. After googling I ran this command

**emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28 -dns-server 8.8.8.8**

but still I am not getting the internet in my emulator. Without VPN the internet on my browser works fine. Any solutions?

This is what I am getting when I do lookup (connected with VPN)

> nslookup facebook.com 8.8.8.8
>
> Server:  dns.google Address:  8.8.8.8
>
> DNS request timed out.
>
> timeout was 2 seconds.
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:    facebook.com
>
> Addresses:  2a03:2880:f153:82:face:b00c:0:25de
>
> 157.240.200.35

Comment: Does the VPN allow UDP traffic to/from the internet? Test on your PC while connected to the VPN if you can use Google DNS server: `nslookup example.org 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: @Robert I edited the question with the nslookup